# jq leaf_paths builtin function is not longer working in jq 1.7, any way to solve it?

Tags: jq

I'm using the builtin `leaf_paths` function for long time.

Recently upgrade for `node.js` modules causing this function to stop working (any json input will work).

I could notice this stopped working (with the same error message between `jq` 1.6 to 1.7)

I still can use the expression on the CLI on `jq` version 1.6:

```
# jq '.|[leaf_paths as $path|{"key": $path | join("^"), "value": getpath($path)}]' /tmp/a.json
 [
  {
   "key": "momo^koko^yoyo^jojo1^access",
   "value": "modify"
  },
  {
   "key": "momo^koko^yoyo^jojo2^access",
   "value": "modify"
  }
 ]

# jq --version
jq-1.6
```

When I upgrade `jq` to 1.7 (which is probably used for the newer `node-jq` module) I'm getting the following:

```
# /tmp/jq-linux-amd64 '. | [leaf_paths as $path | {"key": $path | join("^"), "value": getpath($path)}]' /tmp/a.json
jq: error: leaf_paths/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
. | [leaf_paths as $path | {"key": $path | join("^"), "value": getpath($path)}]
jq: 1 compile error

# /tmp/jq-linux-amd64 --version
jq-1.7
```

Anything I can do to fix it or get the same results using 1.7 (flatten my json into single key value structure)

thanks!

Comment: just saw it been deprecated in 1.7 and been replaced by paths(scalars)

Comment: I was deprecated in 1.5. It was *removed* in 1.7. (But why?!?! That was a completely pointless backwards compatibility break.)

Answer (score 2):

`leaf_paths` was deprecated in favor of the (more universal) `paths(scalars)`. With jq 1.7 use:

```bash
jq '[paths(scalars) as $path | {key: $path | join("^"), value: getpath($path)}]'
```

```json
[
  {
    "key": "0^key",
    "value": "momo^koko^yoyo^jojo1^access"
  },
  {
    "key": "0^value",
    "value": "modify"
  },
  {
    "key": "1^key",
    "value": "momo^koko^yoyo^jojo2^access"
  },
  {
    "key": "1^value",
    "value": "modify"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DRPM53F6V4q)